# document.onkeyup not triggering on dynamically added elements - Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently developing a small Chrome extension that works on any website and am having trouble getting *onkeyup* to fire when the user is selecting any dynamically created elements. I'm not interested if the user is inside of a textarea or input, I just want every key press anywhere on the page to register an event.

Here is just the basic onkeyup function

```
// Wait until everything is loaded
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    // listen for any key presses on the body
    document.body.onkeyup = function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    };
});
```

The problem is that a lot of web pages add content dynamically, and when I'm clicked onto that dynamic content no key presses get registered. For example on gmail, when I click "compose" and the new email editor pops up, my key presses don't register inside of it but register anywhere else on the page.

So I'm wondering if there is a way to 'refresh' my document.body.onkeyup function anytime a new element is added to the page, so that it can listen to that new element as well? Because the extension is to work on any website, I can't know when or how new elements are added to the dom, just that I need the keyup function to 'refresh'

Thanks!

**SOLVED**
See my first comment

Answer (score 0):

Got it solved by first listening for clicks on the document (which seemed to work fine with dynamically created elements, whereas listening for keyup/down did not), and then attaching an event listener to that last clicked element for keyup/down.

```
// Listen for clicks on the document
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    // Set the last clicked element
    let lastClickedEl = e.target.closest('div');

    // Attach a listener to that elment for any typing (keyup)
    lastClickedEl.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
        functionToHandleKeyPresses(e);
    });
});
```